# Why is Period.between not working as expected

Tags: java

Im using the period.between function to get the days between today and july 4th of 2020, but its only printing 16 for some reason, can someone tell me hows the proper way to use this function?

This is my code:

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Period4th {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date today = new Date();
        Date july4 = new Date();
        july4.setDate(4);
        july4.setMonth(6);
        july4.setYear(2020);

        Period daysBetween = Period.between(today.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(),
                july4.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
        System.out.println(daysBetween.getDays());

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use classes `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`; use the new date and time classes in package `java.time` instead.

Comment: Ok I will check that

Comment: Am I under the wrong impression thinking that if the result is "1 year, 0 months, 16 days", `getDays` should correctly return 16? I guess the correct thing is to use `Duration::toDays` instead

Comment: It is far more than 16 days. It is `P1901Y16D`. This is because the year 3920 is 1901 years away from this year (2019), and the 4th of July is 16 days away from this day (18th of June). What else did you expect?

Comment: Seelen I don't get it, why year 3920??

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose the year is clearly 2020 in the code, why would you think it's 3920?

Comment: [`Date.setYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setYear-int-): "Sets the year of this Date object to be the specified value plus 1900."

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose okay but then why its 16 days, it should be then so much more since its year 3920 lol, im trying to compare 18/06/2019 with 4/07/2020, it should be 352 days

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I see, you're right.

Comment: @DanielV see my comment for why it's not 352 or something else. I thought we cleared that out anyway :)

Comment: Oh yes its clear now, thanks mate :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.time.*;

public class Period4th {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate july4 = LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 4);

        System.out.println(Duration.between(today.atStartOfDay(), july4.atStartOfDay()).toDays());

    }
}
```

Thanks guys for the recommendations in comments, its much more easier with java.time package :D